# Splunk Convert Epoch milliseconds to Human Readable Date formatting issue

Tags: epoch, splunk

I have following Splunk Query which is trying to format Epoch captured start and end time into human readable format but seems like splunk is pulling incorrect value here...

```
index=wd_test source=*-1.0.0.log 
| fieldformat c_start=strftime(start,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
| convert timeformat="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" ctime(end) as c_end 
| eval duration=(end-start)/1000
| table start, c_start, end, c_end , duration, sla
```

**I am getting following Result as part of executing above query**

```
start   c_start end c_end   duration    sla
1   1430167363808   12/31/9999 23:59:59 1430167364085   12/31/9999 23:59:59 0.277000    2  
2   1430167236667   12/31/9999 23:59:59 1430167236856   12/31/9999 23:59:59 0.189000    2
```

[image]

Can someone help me here to resolve this issue ? I tried 2 different approaches here but none of them working.

Using the following Online Epoch formatted tool I am able to convert successfully but not using Splunk...

**http://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html**

Answer (score 0):

I tried investigated on this issue and out come is seems like 13 Digits EPOCH time is not supported by Splunk only 10 Digits with EPOCH is supported by Splunk API. As i couldn't able to work with 13 Digits and when i changed form 13 Digits to 10 Digits it worked out well for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
index=wd_test source=*-1.0.0.log 
| fieldformat c_start=strftime(start,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
| convert timeformat="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" ctime(end) as c_end 
| eval duration=***round***(end-start)/1000
| table start, c_start, end, c_end , duration, sla
```

Add round before the `***round***(end-start)/1000`

The epoch time is based on second, not millisecond